# How Mysqli_escape_string or Prepared statement can save me from SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I was reading lots of forums and  answers on Stack over flow  regarding SQL-Injection

and i came to know this is very basic level of SQL-injection

```
  $_POST['name'] = 'xyz;DROP Table users';
  mysqli_query ('select * from abc where name='."$_POST['name']")
```

To prevent this

1. Use mysqli_escape_stirng  on any input that comes from user can save me from SQl-injection
2. Use PDO and prepare statement can also save me from SQL-injection

Q1. What  i want to know  here how passing data to Mysqli_escape_string can save me from  SQL-Injection

```
  $safe_variable = mysqli_escape_String($connection ,$_POST['name'];
```

How mysqli_escape_string  will only save "XYZ" from POST data and leave the rest of the part  (if that is the case)

Q2. How PDO will save me from SQL-Injection

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from ABC where name = :name");
  $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name);
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $stmt->execute();
```

Any help in this regard his highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

> mysql(i)_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function
>   mysql(i)_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: `\x00`, `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"` and `\x1a`.

(http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Note that this depends on the character encoding (**not** workin in this case is `SET NAMES ...` (security risk!!!), `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` should be used!). *(You can read about encoding in my post [Mastering UTF-8 encoding in PHP and MySQL](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/).)*

How does it prevent SQL injection?
- Well it prevents breaking the variables context by escaping `'` etc, the thing is, that `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query` only execute **one** query per *query*, that means, it simply **ignores** `;DROP Table users`.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` **DOES NOT** prevent inserting code like `DROP DATABASE`.

Only PDO and/or `mysqli_multi_query` are vulnerable in this case.

Q2:

The statement is sent to the server first, then the bound variables will get sent seperated and then the statement gets executed, in this case, the security is provided by the database library, not by the client library. You should prefere this.

That means, you first send `$dbh->prepare("select * from ABC where name = :name");` to the server and the database knows your bind param will be inserted into the `:name` placeholder and it will **automatically wrap it properly to not break out of its supposed context**. The database will try to look for a `name` value of `xyz;DROP Table users` and it won't executed any command, just fill that variable space.

Comment: Thanks DAN that completely covers first part of the question  regarding  second question  as you said bound variables are send separately  in my case what if the variable has this value "xyz;DROP Table ABC"  how PDO will prevent this?

Comment: @ahmad05 I added another paragraph hopefully explaining that.

Comment: In lay man term it will just fill :name with "XYZ"  and leave the rest and execute the query ... or will not execute the query at all ?

Comment: @ahmad05 it will (not exactly, but for simplicitly) transform the query to: `select * from ABC where name = "xyz;DROP Table users"` and it will prevent that the variable content breaks out of the quotes `"..."` so you cannot do `select * from ABC where name = "xyz";DROP Table users;--"`.

Comment: Thank you @Dan your answer was simplified was enough for me to understand i got pretty much clear now rest i will learn as  i practise :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with incorporating user input into SQL is that in the resulting SQL you can’t tell which parts were provided by the developer and which by the user. That’s why the developer must ensure that user input gets interpreted as intended.

This is where *string escaping functions* and *parameterization* come in:

**String escaping functions** like `mysqli_real_escape_string` process the value so that it can be securely used in a [string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html) without fearing it may be interpreted as anything else than string data.

However, it is important to note that the value is actually placed in a string literal and nowhere else as it’s only intended for that specific purpose, i. e., it ensures that the passed data is interpreted as string data only when placed inside a string literal. Unfortunately, the PHP manual fails to mention the string literal part.

**Parameterization** as implemented by prepared statements separate the SQL and the data parameters. So there can’t be a confusion of SQL code and provided data. With server-side prepared statements first the statement gets prepared having only parameter placeholders and then the parameter values get passed for execution. And whenever a parameter is encountered, the DBMS uses the corresponding parameter value.

---

As for your specific example:

> What  i want to know  here how passing data to Mysqli_escape_string can save me from  SQL-Injection
>
> ```
>   $safe_variable = mysqli_escape_String($connection ,$_POST['name'];
> ```
>
> How mysqli_escape_string  will only save "XYZ" from POST data and leave the rest of the part  (if that is the case)

It doesn’t because you didn’t put the value in a string literal. However, the following would work:

```
mysqli_query("select * from abc where name='$safe_variable'")
```

> How PDO will save me from SQL-Injection
>
> ```
>   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from ABC where name = :name");
>   $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name);
>   $name = $_POST['name'];
>   $stmt->execute();
> ```

As already said, you explicitly state what the SQL looks like by preparing the statement. And then you pass the parameters for execution. As the parameterized SQL and its parameters are separated, they won’t mix and a passed parameter value can’t be mistaken as SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the case for most SQL escaping functions:

They escape the control chars like `;`, `'`, `"`, ...

So your string

```
xyz;DROP Table users
```

Will be escaped by the functions to

```
xyz\;DROP Table users
```

So your string now isn't a valid SQL command anymore.

But be aware of HTML tags in the data stored in a DB.

If I insert for example

```
<script>alert('foobar');</script>
```

This will be stored in DB and not treated by the SQL escape functions. If you print out the field somewhere again, the JS will be executed by the visitors browser.

So use in addtion [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) for sanitize user input. This is also true for prepared statements.

Comment: In what way does this answer his question?

Comment: Because he's asking how the SQL escape functions and perepared statements will treet his sample value `xyz;DROP Table users`

Comment: It answers Q1. The answer for Q2 would be, that the Statement and the values are sent in different packets to the database and parsed/executed seperated.

Comment: @DanFromGermany That my be true. But I think it's to technical for the question to be answered because he's just asking what happens to his SQL injection string. And not HOW perepared statements work.

Comment: So basically  what will happen my passing data to mysqli_escape_string it will add "\" this to characters   so when the query execute it will return an error  . Right?

Comment: The `;` won’t be escaped, neither by `mysqli_real_escape_string` nor by prepared statements.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes i have read about it   the query will be sent first  and execution plan will be created and than  the parameters are sent

Comment: Now it got Confusing again so what exactly happen  for preventing sql injection